# can my transit visa take me through munich and frankfurt?

Tags: transit-visas

I am going to Nigeria from Mexico but i do have an airport transit visa but i have to stop first in Munich then take a connecting flight to frankfurt before going to Nigeria,would that be possible?

Answer (score 7):

No.  An airport transit visa [does not allow you to pass through border controls into the Schengen area](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/30569/19400).  To fly from Munich to Frankfurt, you need to clear the border control point, entering the Schengen area in Munich.  The trip therefore counts as a "short stay" under the Schengen codes, not as an airport transit.

To follow the indicated itinerary, therefore, you need [one of the following](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa_en):

- a [passport that allows visa-free entry into the Schengen area (pdf)](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/apply_for_a_visa/docs/visa_lists_en.pdf), or
- a Schengen short-stay visa, or
- a long-stay visa or residence permit issued by a Schengen area country.